# A double centralizing theorem for finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, model-theory

I have a proof for the following assertion which employs Model Theory. It has certainly a pure group theoretic proof, but what is such a proof? Is the assertion trivial?

**Theorem**  Let $G$ be a finite group and $s\in G$ be an arbitrary element. Suppose $A=C_{\mathrm{Aut}(G)}(s)$. Then $C_G(A)$ is cyclic.

Edition: By the counterexample of Khalid, it seems that the correct statement is following:

**Theorem**  Let $G$ be a finite group and $s\in G$ be an arbitrary element. Suppose $A=C_{\mathrm{Aut}(G)}(s)$. If $C_G(A)$ has odd order then it  is cyclic.

**Final Edition**

In the light of comments and answers, now I can modify my proof and below is the correct form of the Theorem. The proof still applies a result of Model Theory (Svoninius Theorem on definablity of relations) and I will upload the complete proof to ArXiv in the next days. However the old version (which has errors in the proof of the main theorem) will be available in ArXiv  today (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7621). Here is the corrected Theorem.

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a finite group and $s\in G$ be an arbitrary element. Suppose $A=C_{\mathrm{Aut}(G)}(s)$. Then $C_G(A)$ is a direct product of three cyclic groups.

Thank you again for comments and counterexamples.

Comment: Please clarify your notation. What do you mean by $C_H(S)$? Is this the centralizer of the set $S$ in $H$? If so, then if $G$ is a commutative group, how do you view elements of it inside $Aut(G)$?

Comment: @KhalidBou-Rabee: This is standard notation. If a group $A$ operates on $G$ through automorphisms, then $C_A(S) := \{a\in A \mid {^a s} = s\}$

Comment: I may also be misunderstanding the statement. If we let $G = \langle t \rangle \times \langle s \rangle$ with $|t|=4$, $|s|=2$, then all elements of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ centralize $t^2$, so $C_G(A)$ contains $\langle t^2,s \rangle$, which is not cyclic.

Comment: @Derek No. In your example, A is the full automorphism group of G so C_G(A) is the set of all elements of G that are fixed by all automorphisms, and this is the cyclic group <t^2>.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused. Let $G$ be a higher dimensional (greater than 3) generalized Heisenberg group defined over $F_2$. Select a non-central standard generator, $b$, then if $A = C_{Aut(G)}(b)$ is the set of all automorphisms that fix $b$, then $C_G(A)$, by Marty's definition, is the set of all elements of $G$ that are fixed by $A$, which is not cyclic cause it contains $<b>$ and $Z(G)$ which both generate $F_2 \times F_2$.

Comment: @Khalid Bou-Rabee: I don't know about the structure of generalized Heisenberg group. It is good to explain some details; which automorphisms belong to $A$? Why they fix elements of $Z(G)$?

Comment: Note that this group is just the dihedral group of order $8.$ All of its automorphisms do, of course, fix the unique central involution, so if we take $s$ to be a non-central involution, we seem to obtain a counterexample to the assertion of the problem, as Khalid Bou-Rabee points out.

Comment: @MartyIsaacs Sorry I am completely confused, and I do not understand the comment in  Khalid Bou-Rabee's answer that I am using an alternative interpretation of $C_H(A)$. In my example, since not all automorphisms of $G$ fix $s$, how can $A$ be the full automorphism group of $G$?

Comment: I agree that Derek's example is already a counterexample when $p =2.$

Comment: @DerekHolt I am sorry for that comment. I was confused.

Comment: When G is Abelian of order 8 and exponent 4, there is a unique characteristic subgroup of order 2, and this is indeed centralized by Aut(G). But the other two subgroups of order 2 of G are transitively permuted by Aut(G), and taking s as a generator of either of these produces an element s such that $C_{G}(A)$ is non-cyclic, where $A=C_{{\rm Aut}(G)}(s).$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of my comment (it turns out you don't need the generalized Heisenberg group, just the standard one). My claim is that the theorem as stated is false.

Consider the [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group), $H$, defined over $\mathbb{Z}/2$. This finite group may be described simply as upper triangular matrices in $SL_3(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ with ones along the diagonal.
Let $b$ be the elementary matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
As Johannes Hahn suggested, the group $A := C_{Aut(H)}(b)$ is defined to be all the automorphisms of $H$ that fix $b$. Given Marty Isaacs comment, $C_H(A)$ is defined by:

$$
C_H(A) := \{ g \in H : \forall a \in A, a(g) = g \}.
$$

However, if $\phi : H \to H$ is any automorphism, then $\forall a, b \in H$, we have $\phi([a,b]) = [\phi(a), \phi(b)]$. Thus, if $a$ and $b$ commute, then their images commute. As $\phi$ is surjective it follows that $\phi(Z(H)) \leq Z(H)$. Since $Z(H) = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ and since $\phi$ is injective: $\phi(Z(H)) = Z(H)$. Thus, $\phi$ must fix the element, call it $c$, that generates the center of $H$.

By definition of $A$, for any $a \in A$ we have $a(b) = b$. Further, by the previous paragraph, $\forall a \in A, a(c) = c$. Thus $C_H(A)$ contains $\left< b, c \right>$ which is precisely $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$. This is not cyclic, so the theorem stated in this question does not hold for all finite groups.

**Final remarks.**
There seems to be something special about two here. Maybe the theorem is true if your finite group has order that is not divisible by two? Or perhaps you have a different definition of $C_G(A)$ in mind?

**Update**: Geoff Robinson's answer shows that there is nothing special about two here.

Comment: The group in you example is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8,$ by the way.

Comment: I think you mean ${\rm SL}_{3},$ though.

Comment: Thank you, I checked my own proof, it seems that the order of group is odd. Any way, you can see my proof on ArXive tomorrow (Friday). I am trying to find the gap in the case of groups of even order.

Answer (score 8):

Following the remarks at the end of Khalid Bou-Rabee's answer,I think there will be counterexamples when $p$ is odd. Here's a general strategy to construct them, following pretty much what happens when $p =2$ in that answer. Assume now that $p$ is odd.

It is known that almost all $p$-groups have automorphism group a $p$-group (with an appropriate measure). Take a finite $p$-group $G$ of class $2$ such that $X = {\rm Aut}(G)$ is a $p$-group (we do need $\Omega_{1}(G) \not \leq Z(G).$ Since $G$ has class $2$ and $p$ is odd, this is equivalent to $G$ containing a non-central element of order $p$).
Then $C_{G}(X)$ meets $Z(G)$ non-trivially. Let $z$ be an element of order $p$ in $C_{G}(X) \cap Z(P)$. Now $G$ contain a non-central element $s$ of order of order $p.$ Setting $A = C_{X}(s),$ we see that $\langle z,s \rangle \leq C_{G}(A),$ so that the latter group is not cyclic.

Comment: I find the gap in my proof so I am going to edit the question. But I am not sure if there exists such a $p$-group you talk about in the answer. Is there really a $p$-group of class 2 with automorphism group a $p$-group?

Comment: For example, there is a group of order $3^6$, $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(729,31)$ with automorphism group of roder $3^9$ and a unique central element of order $3$.

Comment: The following (accurate) text was inserted into my answer by Peter Mueller, and should probably be given as a comment: *Added (answering Shahryari's question from the comments)*: For each odd prime $p$ [Heineken and Liebeck](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01238631) (see Section 3) construct  many $p$-groups of class $2$ whose full automorphism group is a $p$-group.